# What does the date in your flagging history refer to?

Tags: support, flag-history

[image: Image of flag history]

On the flag history page, does the date next to the reason for your flag refer to when you flagged the post or when the flag was marked as handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the timestamp of when you flagged.

Flags that haven't yet been acted on have a timestamp too. That page lists your flags chronologically, regardless of when the flags are handled.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have any non handled to compare with